# How to define display name using nested attributes of arguments in ParameterizedTest(name = #{index} multiply {0[0]} x {0[1]} = {0[2]})

Tags: java, junit5, parametrized-testing

I cannot figure out if it is a missing feature, see the [JUnit issue 1154](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1154) and [my comment](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1154#issuecomment-666952289) there, or just my inability to write properly the syntax for **name** of the `@ParameterizedTest` in JUnit5. Given the fact that issue has been open for last 3 years, I'm afraid I cannot wait till I get answer or even the implementation there, so I'm trying to ask here as well.

In my example ParameterizedTest, I'm using `@MethodSource`, which returns a Stream of ints arrays and I would like to use only those array's attributes instead of all `{arguments}` which is anyway same if I use `{0}`. Hard to explain verbally here, better to use code example bellow.

```
package net.delphym.unittests;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class DynamicTestCreationTestParam {
    private static Stream<int[]> data() {
        return Stream.of(new int[][] { {1, 2, 2}, {5, 3, 15}, {121, 4, 484} });
    }

    @DisplayName("Multiplication test")
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "#{index} for {arguments}: {0} x {1} = {2}")
    @MethodSource("data")
    void testWithStringParameter(int[] data) {
        MyClass tester = new MyClass();
        int m1 = data[0];
        int m2 = data[1];
        int expected = data[2];
        assertEquals(expected, tester.multiply(m1, m2));
    }

    // class to be tested
    class MyClass {
        public int multiply(int i, int j) {
            return i *j;
        }
    }
}
```

The test results output looks something like this for the 1st run: `#1 for [1, 2, 2]: [1, 2, 2] x {1} = {2}`

Ideally, I would like to see this: `#1 multiply: 1 x 2 = 2`.

So question is what would be the `@ParametrizedTest(`**name**`)` definition to match my expectation?

I was trying something like this:
`name = "#{index} multiply : {[0][0]} x {[0][1]} = {[0][2]}"`
But it is syntacticly incorrect.

Comment: People on GitHub are very active and they have provided me with nice workarounds/solutions to my needs. Just check a couple of posts bellow my one: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1154#issuecomment-666952289

As I said it's more workaround, still would be good to know if as of now it is limitation of the  JUnit5 or can be somehow achieve when `int[]` is passed in as an arguments

Comment: You can still post the workaround as an answer. It's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, as suggested by [@Murat Karagöz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4467208/murat-karag%C3%B6z), I'm *only* reposting suggestions which I receive on [Github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1154) to have all at one place.

In my opinion, without no doubt, those elegant solutions are only workarounds to the **JUnit5 @ParameterizedTest** API limitations, but they both satisfied my needs.

### Proposed workaround #1 if I don't need to use `int[]`

*Solution presented here is preserving `@MethodSource("data")` and only altering its return type. Now the `data()` method returns **Stream of Arguments** objects (3 in each), instead **Stream of int arrays** (of 3 in each).*

Then the code reads:

```
private static Stream<Arguments> data() {
    return Stream.of(Arguments.of(1, 2, 2), Arguments.of(5, 3, 15), Arguments.of(121, 4, 484));
}

@DisplayName("Multiplication test")
@ParameterizedTest(name = "#{index}: {0} x {1} = {2}")
@MethodSource("data")
void testWithStringParameter(int m1, int m2, int expected) {
    MyClass tester = new MyClass();
    assertEquals(expected, tester.multiply(m1, m2));
}
```

Credits goes to [Marc Philipp](https://github.com/marcphilipp) for [his post @ Github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1154#issuecomment-666956692).

### Proposed workaround #2 to unroll test data to match display needs##

*[This solution](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1154#issuecomment-666956804) provided by [sormarus](https://github.com/sormuras) suggest to use `@CsvSource` instead of the `@MethodSource` and provides the set of the test data within the annotation.*

I like this as simple example how to quickly prepare same basic variation without a need to have a specific data generating method.

The code looks like this:

```
    @DisplayName("Multiplication test")
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "#{index} multiply: {0} x {1} = {2}")
    @CsvSource({"1,2,2", "3,5,15", "121,4,484"})
    void testWithStringParameter(int m1, int m2, int expected) {
        MyClass tester = new MyClass();
        assertEquals(expected, tester.multiply(m1, m2));
    }
```